# How can I solve this non separable ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck trying to solve for the below ODE,

$$
\dfrac{d y}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}+1
$$

it would be trivial to solve if it did not have the one at the end since I could use separation of variables. I tried to use a change of variables $ y = \xi -x$ but that did not get me anywhere. Does a simple solution to this ODE exist?

Comment: it is a simple linear eqution whose integrating factor is $1/x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

Set $\displaystyle\frac yx=v$

$\displaystyle\implies y=vx\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

**Reference** : [Homogeneous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) Ordinary Differential Equation

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I ended up getting $ y = x (c+ln(x))$ which seems to work. Is there a good rule of thumb that you can use to get appropriate substitutions?

Comment: @murphc05, Please follow the link in the answer

Comment: Sorry I had not refreshed to see the link, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\dfrac{d y}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x}+1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{1}{x}\dfrac{d y}{dx}-\frac{1}{x^2}y=\frac{1}{x}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'-(\ln x)'=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{y}{x}=\ln x+c,
$$
for some $c$ constant.